# What are these strange visual artifacts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

It's all over the map. On my PC everything is fine but this happens when I load savegames on my laptop.

Can I fix it somehow?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: What graphics hardware does your laptop have, and what drivers are you on?

Comment: Laptop specs ?Are you video card drivers updated to the latest version ? It seems that you are using mod(s) , remove the mods and check whether the problem persists .

Comment: GTX OC, that's a great notion about mods. Yes indeed I had mods but I'm not sure if here on laptop or on my PC (which I am not able to access). Will look for drivers and try to remove mods.

Comment: If you have trouble in finding out which mods you have installed and if you want a quick way to uninstall them in the future , have a look at the nexus mod manager(assuming you download mods from skyrim.nexusmods.com).

Comment: Jeeze... its the Dark Rainbow! lol... As others have said, Make sure your graphics drivers are up to date and also try adjusting AA settings. With or without mods, this can happen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, though I'm not sure, that some meshes (=3D shape of an object) are screwed up. It looks like an object (item, tower, rock, etc) is streched out from one point. You can probably find which object it is by following the weird strech to the point where it begins.

Have you tried a re-install? That'll probably fix it. Also, try (in your mod manager) to turn of all the mods and see if it happens then (make sure you don't save with the mods off, or all mod-related content may be gone or screwed up if you continue playing with them abled again).

Answer (score 1):

It could be game-related, but it is more likely driver-related or even hardware-related.

Try different driver versions (latest first), and perhaps try running some benchmarking software - this will tax your gfx hardware, possibly giving a indication of a hardware problem. This could be a sign of impending hardware failure or a sign of over-heating - not a surprise with laptops.

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar looking artifacts in the game.
Try toggling your antialising options. Fixed those problems for me...